# What is the difference between ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, autoresetevent, manualresetevent

I have read the documentation on this and I think I understand. An [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) resets when the code passes through `event.WaitOne()`, but a [`ManualResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) does not.

Is this correct?

Comment: May this av will help understanding the difference https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaaRBh07N34

Answer (score 990, accepted):

Yes. It's like the difference between a tollbooth and a door. The `ManualResetEvent` is the door, which needs to be closed (reset) manually. The `AutoResetEvent` is a tollbooth, allowing one car to go by and automatically closing before the next one can get through.

Comment: Even worse, do not wait to long from setting the ARE to the WaitOne, or it will be resetted in the meantime. Had many abandoned threads with that.

Comment: Or like a door and a turnstile.

Comment: Oh, that's why they are named what they are.

Comment: @DanGoldstein well, since this isn't closed and in case someone else wants it:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: you just explained the difference between the words "auto" and "manual".

Comment: ManualResetEvent is like door, all threads under waitone situation will be released once set is called until reset is performed at the next moment

Answer (score 139):

Just imagine that the `AutoResetEvent` executes `WaitOne()` and `Reset()` as a single atomic operation.

The `AutoResetEvent` also guarantees to only release **one** waiting thread.

Comment: Except that if you executed WaitOne and Reset as a single atomic operation on a ManualResetEvent event it would still do something different to an AutoResetEvent. The ManualResetEvent releases all waiting threads at the same time, where as the AutoResetEvent guarantees to only release one waiting thread.

Answer (score 62):

The short answer is yes. The most important difference is that an AutoResetEvent will only allow one single waiting thread to continue. A ManualResetEvent on the other hand will keep allowing threads, several at the same time even, to continue until you tell it to stop (Reset it).

Answer (score 36):

> Taken from C# 3.0 Nutshell book, by
>   Joseph Albahari

[Threading in C# - Free E-Book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

A ManualResetEvent is a variation on AutoResetEvent. It differs in that it doesn't automatically reset after a thread is let through on a WaitOne call, and so functions like a gate: calling Set opens the gate, allowing any number of threads that WaitOne at the gate through; calling Reset closes the gate, causing, potentially, a queue of waiters to accumulate until its next opened.

One could simulate this functionality with a boolean "gateOpen" field (declared with the volatile keyword) in combination with "spin-sleeping" – repeatedly checking the flag, and then sleeping for a short period of time.

ManualResetEvents are sometimes used to signal that a particular operation is complete, or that a thread's completed initialization and is ready to perform work.

Answer (score 21):

I created simple examples to clarify understanding of `ManualResetEvent` vs `AutoResetEvent`.

`AutoResetEvent`: lets assume you have 3 workers thread. If any of those threads will call `WaitOne()` all other 2 threads will stop execution and wait for signal. I am assuming they are using `WaitOne()`. It is like; if I do not work, nobody works. In first example you can see that

```
autoReset.Set();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
autoReset.Set();
```

When you call `Set()` all threads will work and wait for signal. After 1 second I am sending second signal and they execute and wait (`WaitOne()`). Think about these guys are soccer team players and if one player says I will wait until manager calls me, and others will wait until manager tells them to continue (`Set()`)

```
public class AutoResetEventSample
{
    private AutoResetEvent autoReset = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public void RunAll()
    {
        new Thread(Worker1).Start();
        new Thread(Worker2).Start();
        new Thread(Worker3).Start();
        autoReset.Set();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        autoReset.Set();
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread reached to end.");
    }

    public void Worker1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered in worker 1");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 is running {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            autoReset.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    public void Worker2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered in worker 2");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 is running {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            autoReset.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    public void Worker3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered in worker 3");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker3 is running {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            autoReset.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

In this example you can clearly see that when you first hit `Set()` it will let all threads go, then after 1 second it signals all threads to wait! As soon as you set them again regardless they are calling `WaitOne()` inside, they will keep running because you have to manually call `Reset()` to stop them all.

```
manualReset.Set();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
manualReset.Reset();
Console.WriteLine("Press to release all threads.");
Console.ReadLine();
manualReset.Set();
```

It is more about Referee/Players relationship there regardless of any of the player is injured and wait for playing others will continue to work. If Referee says wait (`Reset()`) then all players will wait until next signal.

```
public class ManualResetEventSample
{
    private ManualResetEvent manualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    public void RunAll()
    {
        new Thread(Worker1).Start();
        new Thread(Worker2).Start();
        new Thread(Worker3).Start();
        manualReset.Set();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        manualReset.Reset();
        Console.WriteLine("Press to release all threads.");
        Console.ReadLine();
        manualReset.Set();
        Console.WriteLine("Main thread reached to end.");
    }

    public void Worker1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered in worker 1");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 is running {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            manualReset.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    public void Worker2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered in worker 2");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 is running {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            manualReset.WaitOne();
        }
    }
    public void Worker3()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entered in worker 3");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker3 is running {0}", i);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            manualReset.WaitOne();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

`autoResetEvent.WaitOne()`

is similar to

```
try
{
   manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
}
finally
{
   manualResetEvent.Reset();
}
```

as an atomic operation

Comment: This is only conceptually correct, but not practically. Between the WaitOne and the Reset a context switch might occur; this can lead to subtle bugs.

Comment: Could you up-vote it now ? No one will practically do the second code block here, it's a matter of understanding the difference.

Answer (score 13):

OK, normally it does not a good practice to add 2 answers in same thread, but I did not want to edit/delete my previous answer, since it can help on another manner.

Now, I created, much more comprehensive, and easy to understand, run-to-learn console app snippet below.

Just run the examples on two different consoles, and observe behaviour. You will get much more clear idea there what is happening behind the scenes.

**Manual Reset Event**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplicationDotNetBasics.ThreadingExamples
{
    public class ManualResetEventSample
    {
        private readonly ManualResetEvent _manualReset = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        public void RunAll()
        {
            new Thread(Worker1).Start();
            new Thread(Worker2).Start();
            new Thread(Worker3).Start();
            Console.WriteLine("All Threads Scheduled to RUN!. ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread is waiting for 15 seconds, observe 3 thread behaviour. All threads run once and stopped. Why? Because they call WaitOne() internally. They will wait until signals arrive, down below.");
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
            Console.WriteLine("1- Main will call ManualResetEvent.Set() in 5 seconds, watch out!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _manualReset.Set();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("2- Main will call ManualResetEvent.Set() in 5 seconds, watch out!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _manualReset.Set();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("3- Main will call ManualResetEvent.Set() in 5 seconds, watch out!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _manualReset.Set();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("4- Main will call ManualResetEvent.Reset() in 5 seconds, watch out!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _manualReset.Reset();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("It ran one more time. Why? Even Reset Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled (false), causing threads to block, this will initial the state, and threads will run again until they WaitOne().");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("This will go so on. Everytime you call Set(), ManualResetEvent will let ALL threads to run. So if you want synchronization between them, consider using AutoReset event, or simply user TPL (Task Parallel Library).");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread reached to end! ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        }

        public void Worker1()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker1 is running {0}/10. ThreadId: {1}.", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                // this gets blocked until _autoReset gets signal
                _manualReset.WaitOne();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 is DONE. ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
        public void Worker2()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker2 is running {0}/10. ThreadId: {1}.", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                // this gets blocked until _autoReset gets signal
                _manualReset.WaitOne();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 is DONE. ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
        public void Worker3()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker3 is running {0}/10. ThreadId: {1}.", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                // this gets blocked until _autoReset gets signal
                _manualReset.WaitOne();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Worker3 is DONE. ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Manual Reset Event Output]

**Auto Reset Event**

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplicationDotNetBasics.ThreadingExamples
{
    public class AutoResetEventSample
    {
        private readonly AutoResetEvent _autoReset = new AutoResetEvent(false);

        public void RunAll()
        {
            new Thread(Worker1).Start();
            new Thread(Worker2).Start();
            new Thread(Worker3).Start();
            Console.WriteLine("All Threads Scheduled to RUN!. ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread is waiting for 15 seconds, observe 3 thread behaviour. All threads run once and stopped. Why? Because they call WaitOne() internally. They will wait until signals arrive, down below.");
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
            Console.WriteLine("1- Main will call AutoResetEvent.Set() in 5 seconds, watch out!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _autoReset.Set();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("2- Main will call AutoResetEvent.Set() in 5 seconds, watch out!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _autoReset.Set();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("3- Main will call AutoResetEvent.Set() in 5 seconds, watch out!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _autoReset.Set();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("4- Main will call AutoResetEvent.Reset() in 5 seconds, watch out!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            _autoReset.Reset();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Nothing happened. Why? Becasuse Reset Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block. Since they are already blocked, it will not affect anything.");
            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            Console.WriteLine("This will go so on. Everytime you call Set(), AutoResetEvent will let another thread to run. It will make it automatically, so you do not need to worry about thread running order, unless you want it manually!");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("Main thread reached to end! ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

        }

        public void Worker1()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker1 is running {0}/5. ThreadId: {1}.", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                // this gets blocked until _autoReset gets signal
                _autoReset.WaitOne();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Worker1 is DONE. ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
        public void Worker2()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker2 is running {0}/5. ThreadId: {1}.", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                // this gets blocked until _autoReset gets signal
                _autoReset.WaitOne();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Worker2 is DONE. ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
        public void Worker3()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker3 is running {0}/5. ThreadId: {1}.", i, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                // this gets blocked until _autoReset gets signal
                _autoReset.WaitOne();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Worker3 is DONE. ThreadId: {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }

}
```

[image: Auto Reset Event Output]

Comment: this was the best way to understand it all, copied the code and ran it all whilst changing a few things, understood it well now

Answer (score 9):

**AutoResetEvent** maintains a boolean variable in memory. If the boolean variable is false then it blocks the thread and if the boolean variable is true it unblocks the thread.

When we instantiate an AutoResetEvent object, we pass the default value of boolean value in the constructor. Below is the syntax of instantiate an AutoResetEvent object.

```
AutoResetEvent autoResetEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

**WaitOne method**

This method blocks the current thread and wait for the signal by other thread. WaitOne method puts the current thread into a Sleep thread state. WaitOne method returns true if it receives the signal else returns false.

```
autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

Second overload of WaitOne method wait for the specified number of seconds. If it does not get any signal thread continues its work.

```
static void ThreadMethod()
{
    while(!autoResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Continue");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Thread got signal");
}
```

We called WaitOne method by passing the 2 seconds as arguments. In the while loop, it wait for the signal for 2 seconds then it continues its work. When the thread got the signal WaitOne returns true and exits the loop and print the "Thread got signal".

**Set method**

AutoResetEvent Set method sent the signal to the waiting thread to proceed its work. Below is the syntax of calling Set method.

```
autoResetEvent.Set();
```

---

**ManualResetEvent** maintains a boolean variable in memory. When the boolean variable is false then it blocks all threads and when the boolean variable is true it unblocks all threads.

When we instantiate a ManualResetEvent, we initialize it with default boolean value.

```
ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
```

In the above code, we initialize the ManualResetEvent with false value, that means all the threads which calls the WaitOne method will block until some thread calls the Set() method.

If we initialize ManualResetEvent with true value, all the threads which calls the WaitOne method will not block and free to proceed further.

**WaitOne Method**

This method blocks the current thread and wait for the signal by other thread. It returns true if its receives a signal else returns false.

Below is the syntax of calling WaitOne method.

```
manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
```

In the second overload of WaitOne method, we can specify the time interval till the current thread wait for the signal. If within time internal, it does not receives a signal it returns false and goes into the next line of method.

Below is the syntax of calling WaitOne method with time interval.

```
bool isSignalled = manualResetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

We have specify 5 seconds into the WaitOne method. If the manualResetEvent object does not receives a signal between 5 seconds, it set the isSignalled variable to false.

Set Method

This method is used for sending the signal to all waiting threads. Set() Method set the ManualResetEvent object boolean variable to true. All the waiting threads are unblocked and proceed further.

Below is the syntax of calling Set() method.

```
manualResetEvent.Set();
```

**Reset Method**

Once we call the Set() method on the ManualResetEvent object, its boolean remains true. To reset the value we can use Reset() method. Reset method change the boolean value to false.

Below is the syntax of calling Reset method.

```
manualResetEvent.Reset();
```

We must immediately call Reset method after calling Set method if we want to send signal to threads multiple times.

Comment: Dude, what is the difference between auto and manual?

Comment: @user1034912 In simple words, lets say we have a college and college has a main gate and security. Autoreset event(Security) will check every student(Every WaitOne()) for his id card (Set()) and leave him inside[Every WaitOne() requires a Set()], But manual reset event, once he checks first student for id card, he opens main gate and rest everyone can go

Answer (score 7):

Yes. This is absolutely correct.

You could see ManualResetEvent as a way to indicate state. Something is on (Set) or off (Reset). An occurrence with some duration.  Any thread waiting for that state to happen can proceed.

An AutoResetEvent is more comparable to a signal. A one shot indication that something has happened. An occurrence without any duration. Typically but not necessarily the "something" that has happened is small and needs to be handled by a single thread - hence the automatic reset after a single thread have consumed the event.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, thats right.

You can get an idea by the usage of these two.

If you need to tell that you are finished with some work and other (threads) waiting for this can now proceed, you should use ManualResetEvent.

If you need to have mutual exclusive access to any resource, you should use AutoResetEvent.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to understand AutoResetEvent and ManualResetEvent you need to understand not threading but interrupts!

.NET wants to conjure up low-level programming the most distant possible.

An interrupts is something used in low-level programming which equals to a signal that from low became high (or viceversa). When this happens the program interrupt its normal execution and move the execution pointer to the function that handles this *event*.

The first thing to do when an interrupt happend is to **reset** its state, becosa the hardware works in this way:

1. a pin is connected to a signal and the hardware listen for it to change (the signal could have only two states).
2. if the signal changes means that something happened and the hardware put a **memory variable** to the state happened (and it remain like this even if the signal change again).
3. the program notice that variable change states and move the execution to a handling function.
4. here the first thing to do, to be able to listen again this interrupt, is to **reset** this memory variable to the state not-happened.

This is the difference between ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent.
**If a ManualResetEvent happen and I do not reset it, the next time it happens I will not be able to listen it.**