# manual reset event, Auto reset event

Tags: c#

In C# what is the difference between manual reset event, autoresetevent. Also when should one use the same. What is difference between setting autoresetevent to true or false.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent in .net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/153877/what-is-the-difference-between-manualresetevent-and-autoresetevent-in-net)

Comment: Here is an awesome explanation with pictures :) http://multithreads.blogspot.de/2007/09/eventwaithandler-autoresetevent-and.html

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For the `ManualResetEvent`, once you've called `Set()`, you have to deliberately call `Reset()` to put it back in an unsignaled state such that calls to `WaitOne()` will block.

This is not necessary for `AutoResetEvent`.

The documentation is pretty good on MSDN for [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) and [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx).

Comment: Also note that AutoResetEvent.Set() release only one waiting thread, while ManualResetEvent.Set() release all waiting threads and do not block anymore (until you call Reset).