# C# ManualResetEvent Reset vs WaitOne

Tags: c#, multithreading, manualresetevent

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent?view=net-6.0

I am having a hard time understanding the difference between Reset() and WaitOne().

What is the difference in these two if they are both blocking the thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153877/what-is-the-difference-between-manualresetevent-and-autoresetevent-in-net)

Comment: `.Reset()` does not block at all -- it causes threads that are waiting on the event to block, not the calling thread.

Answer (score 1):

`Set()` and `Reset()` are used when you want to control other threads . `WaitOne()` is used by the threads that shall be synchronized.

BTW, you got the sentence wrong:

> Reset()
>
> Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block.

It says "causing threads" = other threads, not the thread that is calling the method.